# Steam / Doom does not launch

Tags: games, steam

My video card is a GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2 and I use the Latest Proprietary Driver.

I installed Doom with Steam but when I launch it nothing happens!

Logs of /home/adam/.steam/error.log:

```
ExecCommandLine: "'/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam' 'steam://rungameid/379720'"
ExecuteSteamURL: "steam://rungameid/379720"
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to ProcessingInstallScript with ""
installscript_posix.cpp (357) : Assertion Failed: strCommonRedistForeignInstallPath != ""
installscript_posix.cpp (357) : Assertion Failed: strCommonRedistForeignInstallPath != ""
installscript_posix.cpp (357) : Assertion Failed: strCommonRedistForeignInstallPath != ""
installscript_posix.cpp (357) : Assertion Failed: strCommonRedistForeignInstallPath != ""
Proton: Missing or invalid openvrpaths.vrpath file! [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/adam/.config/openvr/openvrpaths.vrpath'
wine: /mnt/windows10/Games/steamapps/compatdata/379720/pfx is not owned by you
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SynchronizingCloud with ""
Proton: Missing or invalid openvrpaths.vrpath file! [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/adam/.config/openvr/openvrpaths.vrpath'
wine: /mnt/windows10/Games/steamapps/compatdata/379720/pfx is not owned by you
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to SiteLicenseSeatCheckout with ""
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to CreatingProcess with ""
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp waiting for user response to CreatingProcess ""
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp continues with user response "CreatingProcess"
Game update: AppID 379720 "", ProcID 29576, IP 0.0.0.0:0
Starting app 379720
>>> Adding process 29576 for game ID 379720
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to WaitingGameWindow with ""
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
GameAction [AppID 379720, ActionID 2] : LaunchApp changed task to Completed with ""
>>> Adding process 29577 for game ID 379720
>>> Adding process 29578 for game ID 379720
Proton: Missing or invalid openvrpaths.vrpath file! [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/adam/.config/openvr/openvrpaths.vrpath'
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_32/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
wine: /mnt/windows10/Games/steamapps/compatdata/379720/pfx is not owned by you
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
ERROR: ld.so: object '/home/adam/.steam/ubuntu12_64/gameoverlayrenderer.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64): ignored.
wine: /mnt/windows10/Games/steamapps/compatdata/379720/pfx is not owned by you
>>> Adding process 29579 for game ID 379720
>>> Adding process 29580 for game ID 379720
Game removed: AppID 379720 "", ProcID 29576 
Uploaded AppInterfaceStats to Steam
Exiting app 379720
No cached sticky mapping in ActivateActionSet.
```

I have installed it on /mnt/windows10 because I don't have enough space on my Ubuntu partition but I have write access on it...

Auto-mount options:

```
nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a permissions error. How is **/mnt/windows10** being mounted?

Comment: It's mounted with 777 permissions `drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4096 janv. 21 13:09 steamapps/`

Comment: Please post the full mount options (add to your question). You'll need to add `uid=1000` to make Linux think you're the owner; regular Linux permissions to not translate from NTFS.

Comment: OK - in the line that says **nosuid,nodev,...**, add `,uid=1000`. You'll need to remount the partition.

Comment: Thanks @ajgringo619 it installed first Direct X then launched the game! Crazy to have Steam working on Linux :) This error was surprising, I could installed the game so I would have never guess it was a write access issue...